# Clear database after testing a rake task using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to test my rake task using rspec and it runs fine, but the problem is that the records aren't being deleted afterwards.

I've put `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` in the config file to no affect. In other tests it's was working fine.

Here's my code:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rake'

describe 'my_app rake tasks'  do
    describe 'rake_task_1' do
        before { MyApp::Application.load_tasks }

        it 'should test it!' do
            10.times { create(:record) }
            Rake::Task["rake_task_1"].invoke
            Record.count.should == 10
        end
    end
end
```

In my rake task I'm executing a query using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`.
I'm sure it has something with SQL transitions in RSepc....

any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) gem?

You can check the [great article by Avdi Grimm](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/) about how to configure it.

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

In file `spec/support/database_cleaner.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! I've used `after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation; DatabaseCleaner.clean }` in that specific file.

Comment: Worked very well! Just put the require in `rails_helper.rb` file:
`require 'support/database_cleaner'`